# DomSanitizer in Angular not working for Transform css property

Tags: angular, transform

I'm using `DomSanitizer` and the `background` css property is working as expected but the `transform` css property isn't working. It results in a blank output.

Where am I making the mistake?

Angular 8:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
get stylish() {
    let basicStyle = `rotate(20deg)`;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`
      transform: -o-${basicStyle};
      transform: -moz-${basicStyle};
      transform: -webkit-${basicStyle};
    `);
  }
get style() {
    let bgStyle = `linear-gradient(left top, #eee, #000)`;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`
      background: -o-${bgStyle};
      background: -moz-${bgStyle};
      background: -webkit-${bgStyle};
    `);
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="tfClass" [style]="stylish"></div>
<div class="bgClass" [style]="style"></div>
```

Output:

```
<div _ngcontent-wsg-c1="" class="tfClass" style=""></div>
<div _ngcontent-wsg-c1="" class="bgClass" style="background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, rgb(238, 238, 238), rgb(0, 0, 0));"></div>
```

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by @waterplea, I made the following changes but the prefixes don't work:

```
get stylish() {
    let basicStyle = `rotate(20deg)`;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`
      transform: ${basicStyle};
      -o-transform: ${basicStyle};
      -moz-transform: ${basicStyle};
      -webkit-transform: ${basicStyle};
    `);
  }
```

The output now shows transform correctly but without prefixes. I need the prefixes:

```
<div _ngcontent-boj-c1="" class="tfClass" style="transform: rotate(20deg);"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS is wrong and browser removes it on its own. Prefixes should go for `transform`, not for `rotate`. I.e.:

```
-o-transform: ${basicStyle};
-moz-transform: ${basicStyle};
-webkit-transform: ${basicStyle};
```

Comment: Happens to the best of us )

Comment: btw, any idea why my style with background image is stripped? `<div class="tfClass" style="background-image: url('http://example.com/needle.png');" [style]="stylish"></div>`. The output is as `<div _ngcontent-jgf-c1="" class="tfClass" style="transform: rotate(20deg);"></div>`. The background-image is missing.

Comment: `[style]` binding does not add to existing style, it replaces it.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it? I updated the question at the bottom.

Comment: What ancient browser set are you supporting? All of those styles work without vendor prefix for about 3-4 years now. You can bind to specific styles like that: `[style.transform]="myTransform" [style.backgroundImage]="myImage"`

Comment: Wait... I made a mistake. it's NOT working. I saw the `background: -o-lineaer..` and thought it's working. It's still showing `<div _ngcontent-uwm-c1="" class="tfClass" style="transform: rotate(20deg);"></div>`. My PDF converted uses webkit.

Comment: See my last comment

Comment: No no.. before we get to backgroud-image, your original answer `-o-transform: ${basicStyle}; -moz-transform: ${basicStyle}; -webkit-transform: ${basicStyle};` isn't working. I was mistaken. It still simply shows `<div _ngcontent-uwm-c1="" class="tfClass" style="transform: rotate(20deg);"></div>`. It's not showing the prefixes.

Comment: Open devtools, click on any element and write this in console:
`$0.style = '-o-transform: rotate(20deg); -moz-transform: rotate(20deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);';` — you would get the same result. Browser removed prefixed versions because it doesn't understand them. Also **they are not needed since IE10**

Comment: I understand but my phantom-html-to-pdf converter needs `-webkit-transform`. It doesn't work only for `transform`.

Comment: For the third time, browser will not allow you to add falsy inline CSS. It doesn't matter what you do.

Comment: I'm using DomSanitizer for this very purpose! To help add this prefix! It's working for `background` but doesn't work for `transform`.

Comment: You cannot do what browser doesn't allow. Did you try what I told you to try? Manually adding this style to an element in devtools?

Comment: Angular and its sanitation has **nothing** to do with it

Comment: Yes. I tried that and understood. My point is coming to the original question of using DomSanitizer which is working for `background` css property but it isn't working for `transform`. I tried as suggested by you in the original answer `-o-transform: ${transformStyle};` but that isn't working. I was mistaken in my first comment. According to your comment, it shouldn't work for `background` css property but it is working. It is converting to `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, rgb(238, 238, 238), rgb(0, 0, 0));` but transform css property won't convert.

Comment: I have added an update to my question. Please check. Thank you for your time.

Comment: No, it is the same for background. Look again at the output you gave, it only has `-webkit-linear-gradient` one, all other values are dropped since they are not recognized.